# How to control a dplyr/tidyr sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

If I have a data-frame like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
d <- tibble(a = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE), x = rnorm(10, 10, 2))
```

And I would like to mutate variable `x`, but only if the constant `FLAG` is true:

```
FLAG <- TRUE
```

Is there an easier way than to define a function like this:

```
my_fun <- function(d, flag = FLAG) {
  if (flag) {
    d %>%
      mutate(x = x * 1000)
  } else {
    d
  }
}

d %>%
  my_fun # works, but function is defined "somewhere else"
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue with your solution? That’s how I’d do it.

Comment: It would make the code easier to read, if I can define this in the pipe flow. Otherwise I have to look up the custom function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm note sure what your intend is, but you can use control flow arguments inside `mutate`. Although that would run the code even if `FLAG` is `FALSE` and then assign `x` to `x` itself. So you could also wrap the whole statement in a control flow.

```r
library(dplyr)

d <- tibble(a = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE), x = rnorm(10, 10, 2))

FLAG <- TRUE

d %>% 
  mutate(x = if (FLAG) x*1000 else x)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    a          x
#>    <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1 a     12818.
#>  2 b     12887.
#>  3 a     15595.
#>  4 a      9171.
#>  5 a      9145.
#>  6 b     12277.
#>  7 a      9361.
#>  8 b     12260.
#>  9 a     11307.
#> 10 b      7182.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Alternatively computationally more efficient, because code is only run when `FLAG == TRUE` otherwise `d` is untouched.

```r
if (FLAG) d <- mutate(d, x = x*1000)
```

---

**Update**

If your intend is to integrate a regular `if` statement into the pipe, then there is the {mpipe} package on Github which has a function called `if_branch`. Here is one example where the `FLAG` is set to `FALSE`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(mpipe)

d <- tibble(a = sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE), x = rnorm(10, 10, 2))

FLAG <- FALSE

# x is left unchanged, but the pipe continuous:
d %>% 
  if_branch(FLAG,
            . %>% mutate(x = x * 1000)) %>% 
  mutate(new = 1) # pipe continuous
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    a         x   new
#>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a     11.3      1
#>  2 b     14.4      1
#>  3 b      9.83     1
#>  4 c      7.56     1
#>  5 b      5.89     1
#>  6 a      8.76     1
#>  7 a     13.9      1
#>  8 c     11.4      1
#>  9 c     10.2      1
#> 10 c     10.6      1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Functions are the fundamental unit of abstraction in R. Use them liberally.

That said, if you want to inline the choice inside your pipeline, you could do the following:

```
d %>% {
    if (flag) (.) %>% mutate(x = x * 100) else .
}
```

I think you’ll agree that this is fairly convoluted:

1. wrapping the right-hand side in `{…}` disables regular parameter substitution for `%>%`. Instead, you’ll explicitly need to use `.`. This allows us to use `if` here.
2. But we can’t just write `. %>% mutate(…)`, because the syntactic sequence `. %>% …` doesn’t perform the usual piping; instead it creates an *anonymous function*. To prevent this (and to get back the regular piping functionality), we need to wrap the left-hand side into `(…)`.

Suffice to say, I do *not* recommend writing this. I recommend using a function.